# is it secure to write mysql_connect ( "localhost", "root", "mypasswd" ) on file?

Tags: mysql

Or somthing like

in `www/html/inc/` folder
`connect_db.php`

`mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "hashed_mypasswd");`

is this more secure?

Or just write
`mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "mypasswd");`
and make the folder (`www/html/inc/`) only accessble from localhost using .htaccess file?

Please help me with a good practice.

Comment: 5 questions 0 accepts. Was every answer you've got not helping you any further?

Comment: you have to connect with your password, so using hashed password gives you nothing but error

Comment: Just store the file securely. Don't log in to mysql with the root user. Don't make the file world readable. And guys, don't paste it to a [pastebin site](http://www.google.no/search?num=100&hl=en&biw=1333&bih=687&q=site%3Apastebin.com+mysql_connect+-localhost+-%22%24host%22+-127.0.0.1+-%22%24db_pass%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)

Comment: @DanielB How do I accept an answer? I'm very newbie here

Comment: now i know how to accept an answer. I see a tick below scoring answers. I will accept answers I've asked so far. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the file will be parsed by PHP, there's nothing to worry about, and the one isn't more secure than the other. Nonetheless, there's practicality involved as well: if you write your mysql_connect in more than one place and you've decided to move your database to another host, or you've decided to change the password, or if you found out it's **absolutely** insecure to connect using the root account (change that ;)), it's easier to have the connect statement in one place.

Also, if PHP isn't parsing your file, you're better off having those critical files *outside* of the webroot, not even accessible by Apache. That's the most secure way.

Comment: Even if PHP is parsing the file, it's better to put it outside of the web root, in case an attacker comes up with an exploit which will cause the web server to send the file directly instead of executing it. (Granted, with the right exploit, being outside the web root may not matter either, but it's at least an additional layer of protection.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store the password on disk then you should encrypt it. This should prevent casual password recovery by a 3rd party. However, the password is most probably sent over the wire in plaintext (not sure about that for MySql).

Comment: Encrypting means it can be decrypted too. If someone can read the file, they'll probably have the means to read the encryption key too. That said, it will still be sent plain text anyway, but if you're only allowing local connections, that shouldn't be much of an issue, I think.

Comment: Absolutely. If the API requires that the password be send in plaintext then the client app must be able to recover the password. This means that the client app can be debugged to recover the password. I still think that storing the password on disk in plaintext is just making it too easy though and that it should be stored in encrypted form.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't hurt, that's for sure, but the security you gain is not that big. Sure, it will make it a little harder to get the password, but I'm more worried about the fact that he's connecting as root ;)

Comment: Minor benefit, but not much, given that anyone able to read the file containing the encrypted file would also be able to read the file containing the keys and algorithms needed to decrypt it. Debugging the app isn't even necessary, given that we're talking about PHP here. Locking down the permissions on the file containing the password is more significant than encrypting it.