# How to access folder outside of domain path in PHP script?

Tags: php, security

Im trying to set-up my PHP SQL Scripts as secure as possible. I went through various posts here, especially [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264372/allowing-only-localhost-to-access-a-folder-where-all-inclusive-php-files-exist).

Here it is recommended to put the config files for the PHP scripts outside of the webaccessible space.

The question: How to access a folder within the script, which is beyond the webaccessible folder structure. And herewith I mean outside of the domain-webspace-directory, by which the script is called?

My PHP Script imports the config via:

```
require_once __DIR__ . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apis/CONFIG/abc-app/file_CONFIG.php";
```

The script is called via the app-abc through subdomain

```
https://api.mysubdomain.ru/abc-app/get_all_SQL_data.php
```

Regarding the webserver folder structure, the above file is located here:

```
/www/htdocs/webhosteraccountid/apis/apis/abc-app/get_all_SQL_data.php
```

Whereas when I access my webspace via FTP on the highest accessible level, I am at

```
//apis/apis/abc-app/get_all_SQL_data.php
```

So /api/ is a first level folder.

My subdomain refers to the folder

```
/www/htdocs/webhosteraccountid/apis/apis/
```

Now back to my script. When I use

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

I get

```
/www/htdocs/webhosteraccountid/apis/apis/
```

So my script always fails, since I never get on a higher folder level than the one accessed by the subdomain. Respetively I never get the true server root directory, only the root of the subdomain.

Therefore the folder in which my config is, appears to be located beyond the DOCUMENT_ROOT. But  how to define a path to such a file? Is this possible? But if not, what is then meant by placing the file into a non-webaccessible folder?

Thanks for hints.

Comment: You can use `..` to move up a level

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550471/php-include-file-in-webroot-from-file-outside-webroot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370053/how-to-include-file-outside-document-root)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. They made the trick. The solution for me keeping above example was:

```
include '../../DB_CONFIG/abc-app_CONFIG.php';
```